# Task Validation Debugging

Tags: plugin-development, tasks

I am having issues debugging craft tasks where the issue is caused by validation errors rather than php syntax / environment issues.

How do you debug validation errors in craft tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Validation errors will still get logged to `craft/storage/runtime/logs` with a `[warning]` label.

Other than that, you options are just like you'd debug anything else in PHP.  Preferably with [xDebug](http://xdebug.org/), but you can always manually `Craft::log()` and read the log files, too.

Comment: Ok great, what are the advantages of xDebug (not used it before). Also is there an easy way log arrays?